# Yocto (poky) common source file location

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto

I have several recipes which use the same source and header files. For example, header file `foo.h` . Each recipe uses this file:

`SRC_URI = "file://foo.h and other files"`

Default search path for a file is “files” folder and folders with the recipe name. I can change this path with `FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/../common_dir:"` and store all shared files inside `common_dir`.
Has yocto some “standard” way to use common directories?

Comment: do you mean a universal `FILESEXTRAPATHS` that all the recipes would use?

Comment: Don't believe there's a standard way to share source, but could you deploy your common source/headers as it's own library which is a dependency on your application recipes?

Comment: @mascoj Library with common files solve the problem, but we need the solution when those files are outside yocto layer.